# how I can set EIO version?

Tags: python, python-socketio

My code is:

```
uri="wss://api.my.site"
sio = socketio.Client(logger=True, engineio_logger=True)
sio.connect(uri, transports=["websocket"])
sio.wait()
```

and into log I get string

```
Attempting WebSocket connection to wss://api.my.site/socket.io/?transport=websocket&EIO=4
```

but my server use EIO=3

How i can change EIO version?

I try use:

```
sio.connect(uri, transports=["websocket"], eio=3)
```

but this not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set the `EIO` parameter directly, you have to use versions of the `python-socketio` and `python-engineio` packages that are compatible with the protocol version that you need.

See the [version compaitiblity](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#version-compatibility) table in the documentation. The value of `EIO` is shown in the engine.io protocol revision column.